# Leaflet Clustering markers with popups and zoom to pin closes the pin when at same lat lng

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Essentially I have leaflet with clustered markers. On popup open I zoom to the marker and when there is a marker at the exact same location, the spiderify disappears and it closes the pop up.

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
var offsetPan;
var marker = e.popup._source;

marker.name = marker._tooltip._source._tooltip._content;
marker.unbindTooltip();

map.invalidateSize(true);

if(width <= 400){
    offsetPan = [0, -250];
} else {
    offsetPan = [0, -450];
}

map.flyToBounds([
    marker._latlng
], {
    paddingBottomRight: offsetPan
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I zoom to the marker [...] the spiderify disappears and it closes the pop up.

That is expected behaviour of Leaflet.markercluster plugin: whenever the map zoom changes, if a Cluster is spiderfied, the spiderfication is closed, which hides the child Markers, hence closes any of their Popup.

Comment: Is there a way to override this functionality? or perhaps a better way to zoom to marker instead of on popup open?

Comment: Ah nevermind went with the option to not zoom if it is spiderified on clusterclick